# what is the equivalent PercolateQueryBuilder in spring data elastic search?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-percolate

**Bottom line** - How do I turn my simple percolator query to spring data elastic search? Any leads are appreciated. Thanks

I have been trying to write the below percolate query using spring data elastic search

```
"query": {
    "percolate": {
      "field": "query",
      "document": {
        "message": "A new bonsai tree in the office"
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria("query").is(

            new Criteria("percolate")
                                .is(
                                        new Criteria("field").is("query")
                                                .and("document")
                                                .is(new Criteria("message").is(text))
                                )
    );
```

Tried

```
Query query = new StringQuery(String.format("{\n" +
                "  \"query\": {\n" +
                "    \"percolate\": {\n" +
                "      \"field\": \"query\",\n" +
                "      \"document\": {\n" +
                "        \"message\": \"%s\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}",text));
```

Also tried NativeSearchQuery but none of them worked.

I see https://tothepoint.group/matching-documents-with-elasticsearch-percolator-query/ where the author uses PercolateQueryBuilder  (https://github.com/ophalsp/elasticsearch-percolator ) but I dont see PercolateQueryBuilder in spring data elastic search.

**EDIT:-**
I tried all the builders that implement QueryBuilder. Since none of them have **query or percolate** in the XContentBuilder builder (as shown below) they do not work

```
protected void doXContent(XContentBuilder builder, Params params) throws IOException {
        builder.startObject("query");
```

I can also see that PercolateQueryBuilder is part of percolator-client that is part of org.elasticsearch.client.transport which is excluded in spring-boot

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I will add org.elasticsearch.client.transport and give it a shot.

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch has an explicit dependency on `org.elasticsearch.client:transport` in it's pom. Why the makers of Spring Boot exclude this - I have no idea.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch - I tried spring-data-elasticsearch in a 
NON spring boot project and I am getting 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/NativeDetector but 
when I exclude org.elasticsearch.client:transport from spring-data-elasticsearch
and add it as a separate dependency I do not get the error. So this could be the reason.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question with the success I had. Might help someone.

After adding the below dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>7.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

and with the below code I was able to run query on the Percolator.
I dont know why spring-boot removed the above dependency. So far I dint face any issue. If I face issue because of the above dependency I will update here.

```
public Query buildLookUpQuery(String text){
        XContentBuilder docBuilder = null;
        try {
            docBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject();
            docBuilder.field("message", text);
            docBuilder.endObject();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            log.error("Unable to build a query ", ioException.getMessage());
        }
        PercolateQueryBuilder percolateQuery = new PercolateQueryBuilder(QUERY,
                BytesReference.bytes(docBuilder),
                XContentType.JSON);
        return new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(percolateQuery)
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: Amazing, you've saved me a bunch of time!